# ImportError when importing Basemap

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap

I have problems importing basemap, even though I just installed it via `pip install basemap`. I've tried both with python2.7 and python3:

```
python3
>>> from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits'

python2.7
>>> from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _geoslib
ImportError: libgeos_c.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm on a ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What worked for me on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libgeos-3.4.2
sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev
sudo pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get the following error on `sudo apt-get install libgeos' :  `Unable to locate package libgeos` - but libgeos-3.4.2 worked. Ater following your solution step by step I did python2.7 -> `from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap` and it worked, thank you!

Comment: @bjornasm, sorry I actually meant `libgeos-3.4.2`, it was a copy paste error.

Comment: Many years later: libgeos-dev libgeos-3.5.0 libgeos-c1v5  sudo pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip worked great.  Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me in python3 with v3.1.2 of matplotlib:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y python3-mpltoolkits.basemap
```

Check matplotlib module version running in python:

```
>>>import matplotlib
>>>matplotlib.__version__
'3.1.2'
```

Upgrade module:

```
sudo pip3 install matplotlib --upgrade
```