# No module named basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, matplotlib-basemap, matplotlib-widget

Following the instructions in  [this page](https://peak5390.wordpress.com/2012/12/08/matplotlib-basemap-tutorial-installing-matplotlib-and-basemap/),I downloaded the basemap and its dependencies. When I run

> sudo apt-get install python-mpltoolkits.basemap

It gives me the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-mpltoolkits.basemap is already the newest version (1.0.7+dfsg-3build2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

the same thing for

> sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib

But running the simpletest.py in the examples folder, gives me the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simpletest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
ImportError: No module named basemap
```

I also tried the other method described the [same page](https://peak5390.wordpress.com/2012/12/08/matplotlib-basemap-tutorial-installing-matplotlib-and-basemap/) for installing from the source but the output is the same.I am running on ubuntu16.04 LTS. Any idea!

Comment: the answer presented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333431/importerror-when-importing-basemap) works for me

Answer (score 1):

if you're using Anaconda, it has a package for basemap:
    conda install basemap